# Android image strip and edit / combine 2 pictures

Tags: java, android, image, image-processing, edit

I want to create an android app that takes 2 pictures (taken from the phone camera). Takes the top part of pic1 and the bottom part of pic2 and combines them to the final picture.

I'm thinking about converting each image to byte array. Then take the half values from the array of the first image and the other half from the other image, merge them in the final array and convert that array back to image.  Is it feasible? Is this a good solution or there is any better practice for this?

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess I found the solution. There is a class in the Java6 API called "BufferedImage". This class has the methods:  setRGB , getRGB  where you can get the int value of the rgb color for the pixel you specify. This way you can get the pixel color from the image you want and set it in the target image.

Answer (score 0):

Try using OpenCV. It will be very fast since it will be handling the images in native code. Convert Bitmap objects into Matrix(OpenCV) object and send the address to the native code where you can do these computations very easily. If any code is required, do let me know.